# For what $p$ is $x^p$ Lebesgue Integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Revising for an exam on Monday any help with the following question would be greatly appreciated;

If $f$ is a function on $(0, \infty)$ taking values in $\mathbb R$, defined $f(x)=x^p$ ($p$ is a real number) for which values of $p$ is $f$ Lebesgue integrable?
Thanks.

Comment: For any $p\in\mathbb R$, $x^p$ is not integrable on $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: Do you know the answer and are looking for a proof, or do you not even know the answer?

Comment: sorry for x^p on (0,infinity)

Comment: Convergence at $0$ requires $-p<1$. And at $+\infty$, we need $-p>1$.

Comment: so @julien what if it was on (0,1)

Comment: On $(0,1)$, $x^p$ is integrable if and only if $-p<1$. Note that this is all very easy, at $0$ like $+\infty$. What is an antiderivative of $x^p$?

Comment: ok i think i have got it on (0,1) integrable iff p>-1 and then on (1,infinity) integrable iff p<-1, so in (0, infinity) it is integrable nowhere.

Comment: Correct. The conclusion is rather that it is not integrable for any $p$.